# Getting started with converting code behind to client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, html

I am wanting to convert the code behind portion of my `asp.net web forms` application to client side ajax, javascript... not sure what.

The reason I want to do this is so the application will be able to work offline if internet connection is lost.

I have `linq2sql` databound controls and I know this will take some work.

I am just hoping that somebody out there can point me in the right direction so that I don't waste a lot more time.

Eventually I will convert this app to `MVC`, but I have a lot of learning to do.

Comment: If you need to access a database on the server then your code won't work offline in any case. So the first thing you'd need to do is send _all_ the data the page could need to the client. If this isn't possible then based on what you've said neither is the goal of making the page work offline.

Comment: Yes, I expect to bring the data to the client and use JQuery or something to bind the data to gridviews and listviews.  If that's possible. 
If necessary I will change out the bound controls and use jQuery grids, to work with data.I am not sure of the best technology to use to convert the code behind to client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's not entirely a simple task. However, you can make it easier if you plan out your steps.

I would start by building out a site map. Then identify which pages will be converted to views and which controls will be converted to partial views or HTML Helpers.

Example:

You have Default.aspx as a Web Forms page. Default.aspx uses a GridControl.ascx control. In MVC that could be a Index view on the Home Controller that uses a GridControl partial view.

Once you have mapped out all of these parts of your site it will be a lot easier to write the code. I would definitely recommend having the plan mapped out before you go forward and start writing code.

Comment: I have a primary page within my application that I have already taken out asp.net controls and replaced with client side code, like a tab control and menu. I also use divs instead of controls, but there are listviews and gridviews that are bound either in code behind or directly to a linq data control.  
Should I convert these controls to jQuery and then use another technology to read and write data?  
I wish I could convert the app to MVC now, but I am still learning it and haven't quite absorbed the full process.
I am still trying to figure out if the code behind goes in the controller,

Comment: Watch this free course from PluralSight. It will help you understand MVC a whole lot better. http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

Comment: I actually have a subscription with them and have watched a lot of the videos, including MVC.  I am watching one now. Although I've been a programmer for 20+ years, I come from the COBOL era and it takes me a while to grasp it, unless I have an example.

Comment: Basically, would you normally put your code-behind in a controller or Linq to Entities or both.  I know asp.net web forms and linq to sql, but simple things like the code-behind part confuses me.